# In For loop using two elements in python

Tags: python, for-loop

In python list I have two items per element, 1st a str, second a float

```
L= [('A', Decimal('52.00')), ('B', Decimal('87.80')), ('G', Decimal('32.50'))]
```

I want use a `for loop` both item in the element

```
NewL= []
for row in L:

    ### do something with str
    InSql= "SELECT  " % str
    f= csr.execute(InSql)
    ns = list(f)  

    ###do something with float
    InSql= "SELECT  " % float
    f= csr.execute(InSql)
    nf = list(f) 

    NewL.append(str, float,ns, nf)
```

Comment: You have not asked a question! ;-)

Comment: Shadowing names of built-ins is a bad idea. Choose a more descriptive name that actually says somethough about what these strings and numbers represent.

Comment: @delnan, I that for clarity of Q.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your `for` loop to something like this:

```
for str_data, float_data in L:
    # str_data is the string, float_data is the Decimal object
```

Comment: Is str_data, float_data ordered by orginal L? Does this order change?

Comment: The order is preserved, so as long as each tuple in `L` is ordered the same way you are guaranteed that `str_data` will be the string and `float_data` will be the `Decimal`.

Answer (score 3):

Two ways:

First you could access the members of row:

```
#For string:
row[0]
#For the number:
row[1]
```

Or you specify your loop this way:

```
for (my_string, my_number) in l:
```

Answer (score 3):

Reading your question, I think what you want is this:

```
L= [('A', Decimal('52.00')), ('B', Decimal('87.80')), ('G', Decimal('32.50'))]

for my_str, my_float in L:
    print "this is my string:", my_str
    print "this is my fload:", my_float
```

Answer (score 3):

Tuple unpacking works with loop variables:

```
L= [('A', Decimal('52.00')), ('B', Decimal('87.80')), ('G', Decimal('32.50'))]
for s, n in L:
    print "string %s" % s
    print "number %s" % n
```

ouputs:

```
string A
number 52.00
string B
number 87.80
string G
number 32.50
```